# Tradable Volatility

Tags: volatility

VIX (spot) has very nice features, including mean reversion. We all know that we can't trade VIX (spot). The closest we can get is using front-month future contracts. The problem I have with that is that, in practice, VIX futures are not great at tracking VIX. Is there a way to replicate tradable VIX?

Comment: By trading the future contracts, you loose the long term mean reversion property. Each time you roll from one future to another, you break the mean reversion.

Comment: How is this different than [Trading a synthetic replication of the VIX index](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/139/trading-a-synthetic-replication-of-the-vix-index)?

Comment: Agree with Josh. This is an exact duplicate. Voting to close.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some older answers:

[Trading a synthetic replication of the VIX index](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/139/trading-a-synthetic-replication-of-the-vix-index)

[SPX options vs VIX futures trading](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/249/spx-options-vs-vix-futures-trading)